# request parameters and add as session attributes

Tags: java, session, servlets, attributes

I was given this as an in class problem and recievd 0 as the result, but I can't find the fault with it. The questions is **Write the lines of code you would need to use in a servlet to retrieve a parameter
from an incoming request and add it to the session as an attribute:**

My answer:

```
String param1= request.getParameter("param1");

HttpSession session= request.getSession();
String parameter1= (String)request.getAttribute("param1");
session.setAttribute("param1", parameter1);
```

Also, is the '(String)' necessary in the second line? or just good practice? 
Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've made a very common mistake, confusing attributes with parameters.  In your code you have:

```
String parameter1= (String)request.getAttribute("param1");
```

Attributes can be thought of as meta-data of the request.  For example, if the request is made via SSL then you can get data about the request from the attributes.  Take a look at the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getAttribute-java.lang.String-) for `getAttribute` for more details.

Parameters, on the other hand, can be used to get URL parameters.  Your last question actually points you in the correct direction - `getParameter()` already returns a String so you don't need to cast it.

Properly written the line above should be:

```
String parameter1= request.getParameter("param1");
```

Answer (score 0):

getParameter() - used to get url parameter from request in server side(java side).

Where as If you want to fetch any values from java side to jsp(view side)
you can use setAttribute() in Server side(Java side) and get the value using getAttribute() from jsp.